# Any hint on how to find minimum number of steps to mark all element of given array according to given conditions?

Tags: c, algorithm

Two integers `N<=10^5` and `K<=N` are given, where `N` is the size of array `A[]` and `K` is the length of continuous subsequence we can choose in our process.Each element `A[i]<=10^9`. Now suppose initially all the elements of array are unmarked. In each step we'll choose any subsequence of length `K` and if this subsequence has unmarked elements then we will mark all the unmarked elements which are minimum in susequence. Now how to calculate minimum number of steps to mark all the elements?

For better understanding of problem see this example--

`N=5 K=3`
`A[]=40 30 40 30 40`

Step 1- Select interval [1,3] and mark A[1] and A[3]

Step2- Select interval [0,2] and mark A[0] and A[2]

Step 3- Select interval [2,4] and mark A[4]

Hence minimum number of steps here is 3.

**My approach(which is not fast enough to pass)-**

I am starting from first element of array and marking all the unmarked elements equal to it at distance `<=K` and incrementing `steps` by 1.

Comment: yeah but help me in order to find a fast solution.

Comment: It's very easy to construct sample inputs so that the number of steps will be N-1. Why do you expect to be able to find a faster solution ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark how N-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider how you'd answer the question for `K` == `N` (i.e. without any effective restriction on the length of subsequences).  Your answer should be that the minimum number of steps is the number of distinct values in the array.

Then consider how this changes as `K` decreases; all that matters is how many copies of a `K`-length interval you need to cover the selection set `{i: A[i] == n}` for each value `n` present in `A`.  The naive algorithm of walking a `K`-length interval along `A`, halting at each position `A[i]` not yet covered for that value of `n` is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand your answer. Can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: @hellcoder consider each distinct value `v` in isolation. Check how many subsequences of length `K` you need to cover all positions `i` with `A[i] == v`.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok now i got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As we see  minimum number of steps = N/k or N/k+1 and maximum number of steps =(n+k-1).
We have to optimize the total number of steps and which depend on past history of choices we made which refers to dynamic solution.

For dynamic theory tutorial see http://www.quora.com/Dynamic-Programming/How-do-I-get-better-at-DP-Are-there-some-good-resources-or-tutorials-on-it-like-the-TopCoder-tutorial-on-DP/answer/Michal-Danil%C3%A1k

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved in O(n) as follows:
Trace each element a[i]. If a[i] wasn't traced before then map the number and its index and increase counter.If the number was traced previously then check whether its (last index-curr_index)>=K if yes update the index and increase count. Print count.
Map STL will be beneficial.