# minimum number of steps required to set all flags of array elements to 1 which were initially 0 by default

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any hint on how to find minimum number of steps to mark all element of given array according to given conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291517/any-hint-on-how-to-find-minimum-number-of-steps-to-mark-all-element-of-given-arr)

suppose an array of length n is provided. further we are also provided with a subsequence length of k

ie say array is [1,2,3,5,5]........ (here n is 5) and subsequence length is 3..(it means any subsequence of length 3 can be taken)

example of subsequences in above example are {1,2,3} or {2,3,5} or {3,5,5}

Now, a 'step' here is defined as take any subsequence of length k from the array,once taken you can set the flags of minimum array elements of subsequence to 1. explanation:. say your array is {1,2,3,5,5} ie n is 5 and say 'k' value is 3. then following selections can be made {1,2,3}(element '1' flag set),{2,3,5}(element '2' flag set),{3,5,5}element '3' flag set,{3,5,5}element '5' flags set.

NOTE:. once flag of a particular element is set to 1 that particular element is not considered for determining minimum in a subsequence.

A dynamic programming or a optimal approach is required. My code works but is not optimal. link to my code:. http://pastebin.com/LfCH79zA input format for my code:. http://pastebin.com/wHqJTy0Y

RECURSIVE FORMULATION

this is my code:.http://pastebin.com/5QJNLEqy
base condition is very clear and appears very correct too.

but i am facing problem in forming recursive condition formation

here's my code in which i have clearly mentioned my recursive condition but it doesn't appear to be giving correct results.

can anyone please tell error in it.

I ahve already referred the link:.[Any hint on how to find minimum number of steps to mark all element of given array according to given conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291517/any-hint-on-how-to-find-minimum-number-of-steps-to-mark-all-element-of-given-arr)

Comment: Your problem description leads to "number of steps" = "number of different array elements" (you can set just one flag in each step to 1, and as long as there are flags with the value 0, there is always a subsequence containing a corresponding element). That's probably not the problem you wanted to get solved.

Comment: @DocBrown how it leads to number of different elements,
i mean consider an example
array->{40,30,40,30,40}
here answer will be 3
explanation:.{30,40,30}(both 30's flag set),{40,30,40},{40,30,40}

Comment: Ok, I read the other post you linked to. That description is clearer (and does not contain a misleading example, like yours above). But since the question was already asked there, I don't see any reason why we should not close your question as a duplicate.